# How do you show failed test comments on Team foundation server

Tags: tfs

I have added comments on failed tests within tfs but these cannot be shown any where even when you click into the test. How can one show the comments entered on tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you're working in Team Web Access rather than the Test Manager client?

I'd be happy to be proved wrong on this but I don't believe you can view the comments directly in Web Access.

If you open up the test details pane (right hand side of your Test Plan view)
[image]

Then you can select Test Results in the Pane menu
[image]

If you double click the test result or click the Open in Microsoft Test Manager button (beside Refresh) then it will launch MTM (assuming you have it installed) and you will see more details including the individual steps and any comments you added.

You can also go to this directly in MTM on the Test tab and select Analyse Test Runs.  Double click the run you want the details of.

If you're not using MTM then you could associate the test run fail with a Bug (click the Create Bug button on the test runner) and you test steps and comments will be added to the Bug Work Item steps to reproduce.

Comment: Correct. Am working with the web based tfs. Strange that one cannot retreive or view the same coments entered on tfs unless you do so via and entirely different app.

Comment: I did a bit of digging and found the work item fields are configurable - add, modify etc is possible. Questions is how to do that on the web version of tfs.

Comment: There is no Open in Microsoft Test Manager button beside the refresh button.  When you open the MTM The test suites from the server are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

As rerwinRR mentioned, this is not possible in team web access. But you may vote for this feature wish:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/11336064-give-possibility-in-team-web-access-to-see-the-com

Answer (score 1):

In TFS 2015 web interface, open the *TEST* tab, *Test plan*, choose the test suite from the dropdown.

Choose the test case on the second pane.

Press the *Show/hide details pane* button from the second pane's toolbar.

[image: Show/hide details pane]

When the third pane shows up, choose *Test results* from the *Pane* dropdown at the top right. You will see the list of test runs for the selected test case.

Doubleclick one of the test runs to see the details, including comments you have added to the steps.

Comment: There is no Show hide details pane button on second pane's tool bar

Comment: @user1161391 there is, see screenshot.